# How to determine the channel mapping (channel-to-track allocation) of a surround sound audio signal

Tags: c, matlab, signal-processing, real-time, dolby

I'm working on a system that where I'm processing surround sound signals (Dolby Digital 5.1) real-time.

Because it's a real-time application I don't know in prior what kind of channelmap the audio signal has. There are a variety of different configurations (FL,C,FR,LF,BL,BR)(FL,FR,C,BL,BR,LF) and so on..

So far I think there might be some pattern in which audio codec the audio signals are encoded in (.ac3, .dts, .aac), but no certainty.

DD 5.1 only puts out recommendations and guidelines,  but again no pre-specified configurations.

How do I determine the channelmapping based only on my 6-channel input stream? Does it contain some kind of header information maybe?

FYI I'm working in Matlab using their Audio System Toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there is *no* obvious way to do this as such a signal decoder is a separate product from Dolby.

These decoders are installed into DVD players, sound cards etc., that has to process surround signal real-time.

If you build any application that uses such devices already - **the device streamlines the signal for you** and you can process the signal further after that point in the signal way.